# If a person is randomly selected, how much money will he/she have?

Tags: statistics

If a person is randomly selected, then what is the average amount of dollars he/she will have?

Answer is 1.064.

Given:

958 people have 1 dollar each.

26 people have 2 dollars each

11 ........... 3 dollars each

4 ............ 4 dollars each

1 ............ 5 dollars each

I am trying to find the answer to another hashing problem by understanding this problem (average number of searches in a hash table using chaining). I tried thinking of as assigning "weights" so that the final answer will lean more towards $1 but I'm not sure how to go any further please help.

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average = Total Dollars/Total People

Total Dollars = $958\cdot1 + 26\cdot2 +11\cdot3 + 4\cdot4 + 1\cdot5 = 1064$

Total People = $1000$

Average = ${1064\over 1000} = 1.064$